# How to check if hashmap contains the key before getting it in the shortest way?

Tags: java

Is there any shorter way to find if the key already exists before getting it?

```
    Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
    if (map.containsKey("2")) {
        fee.put("2", fee.get("2") + 12.00);
    } else {
        fee.put("2", 12.00);
    }
```

I want to add up the value.

Comment: map.getOrDefault("2", 0.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor it to use [getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method from `Map` as follows:

```
   Map<String, Double> fee = new HashMap<>();
   fee.put("2", fee.getOrDefault("2", 0.0) + 12.00);
```

Another way of doing it could be using `Optionals`:

```
    Map<String, Double> fee = new HashMap<>();
    fee.put("2", Optional.ofNullable(fee.get("2")).orElse(0.0) + 12.00);
```

Answer (score 4):

The most concise way to do this is:

```
map.merge(key, 12.0, Double::sum);
```

As described in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)), this default implementation is equivalent to:

```
 V oldValue = map.get(key);
 V newValue = (oldValue == null) ? value :
              remappingFunction.apply(oldValue, value);
 if (newValue == null)
     map.remove(key);
 else
     map.put(key, newValue);
```

where `remappingFunction` is `Double::sum` in this case.